# Heap Analytics (iOS) - Is it possible to track counts of number of items (photos) selected each time a user goes to the page?

Tags: ios, analytics

I need to use Heap Analytics to count number of photos selected each time user goes to a page to select pages.

The problem I am facing is that I can not distinguish unique page visits for a particular user so count of number of items keeps growing no matter when when I as the single user visit the page.  Currently, the graph I am generating shows an aggregate count of all times I visit the page and select photos.

How do I segregate page view instances in Heap Analytics to properly capture unique visits to a page and count each visits' number of items selected.

Comment: how about Firebase Analytics?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,  I don't know Firebase, and unfortunately I am limited to use of Heap Analytics.

Comment: Does heap (web version) allow for counting DOM elements on a page, not events?

Answer (score 0):

Try https://fabric.io it is very easy to implement and has a lot of features that you might need in the future.